# How to query comma separated values in Postgres string field? ROR / ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I'm using Ruby on Rails 4.2.3 and I have two string fields in `users` table `two_factor_secret_key` and `two_factor_recovery_codes`. The first one has a string token while the second one has ten tokens separated by `;`. They look something like:

```
[62] pry(main)> ap User.last
  User Load (6.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY "users"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
#<User:0x007f8b3b009ad8> {
                              :id => 1,
                           :email => "test@me.com",
               ......
               ......
           :two_factor_secret_key => "jvyzizqib47gp4au",
       :two_factor_recovery_codes => "jgbcfjzh3lhpm6dv;er34rihizdlzu4fc;u32wwdmxl2dnxslv;liqcswrhjyfrpbkk;ttuezeszxnwzjent;4noxzmo4rg5jed5w;eynndg2gy5yzrdi3;h275valgjiiee7r3;f6m5xwujmtnucshe;tvhzxibvj4ikulyg"
}
```

How can I query users table in a way I search `two_factor_secret_key` and `two_factor_recovery_codes`.

In this example if the query was based on `jvyzizqib47gp4au` I would like to return the user and the same if I use `er34rihizdlzu4fc` I should get true as it's included in `two_factor_recovery_codes`?

It's easy to find the record using `two_factor_secret_key` with something like: `User.where(two_factor_secret_key: "jvyzizqib47gp4au")`, however I'm not sure how should I query `two_factor_recovery_codes` with `;` separated values.

Please note that I don't wanna use serialization with activerecords as ROR app is not the one who is responsible of generating the data in my case.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
user = User.where("two_factor_secret_key LIKE :search OR two_factor_recovery_codes LIKE :search", search: "%jvyzizqib47gp4au%")
```

Comment: Thanks for your willing to help @Shannon. My problem is with `two_factor_recovery_codes` not `two_factor_secret_key`. How should I search in a list of `;` separated strings

Comment: Thanks again Shannon. Not really it doesn't. try to change search from `jvyzizqib47gp4au` to `er34rihizdlzu4fc` (2nd value in `two_factor_recovery_codes `) and it wont find the record.

Comment: Ok I think this was close. Please update your answer as the search should be something like `search: "%jvyzizqib47gp4au%"` I guess